# Android:Changing layout theme where saved?

Tags: android-layout, android-manifest, android-theme

I have two issues:

**1** When i use to develop android application on eclipse i remarked that in layout editor there is the ability to change the theme,but i can't to figure out where these modifications are saved.

**2** In AndroidManifest.xml whene i apply a light theme  for an activity still it's black

*Style file contains:*

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
```

*Manifest file contains:*

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"/>
```

I am having trouble to figure out these issues.

Thank you in advance